# Equivalent C# of this PHP code

Tags: c#, php, mysql

Trying to learn C# and I can't quite get a handle on querying and getting results.  I'm trying to figure out both how to and the best way of doing the below in C# .NET.  It's a MySql database.

```
//Interact with the DB. Find out if this hashed account #'s in there.
$dbh = $this->getPDO();
$procedure = "SELECT userPass FROM 499Users WHERE accName = :acc";
$call = $dbh->prepare($procedure);
$call->bindParam(':acc', $testAcc, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$call->execute();

//Fetch up to 1 result row
$row = $call->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This is my latest try: **Also I realize I should probably be using parameters, but I just want it to work first**

```
MySqlConnectionStringBuilder conn_string = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();

conn_string.Server = "*";
conn_string.UserID = "*";
conn_string.Password = "*";
conn_string.Database = "*";
conn_string.Port = 3306;

MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(conn_string.ToString());


try
{
    Console.WriteLine("Trying to connect to: ..." + conn_string); Console.WriteLine("Connecting to MySQL...");

    connection.Open();

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}

string hashedAcc = this.HashPassword(acc);
//Verify hashed account
string query = "SELECT userPass FROM 49Users WHERE accName =" + hashedAcc;

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

MySqlDataReader myReader;
myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
try
{
    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(myReader.GetString(0));
    }
}
finally
{
    myReader.Close();
    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Ya:  An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.CF.dll     *Fatal error encountered during command execution.*

Comment: Sorry:    other exception is - *Additional information: Unknown column '$2y$10$jxRs9MbE85wXjVT4A2hAFOKuDNZsEWMJvgNHZWZI3i4mXwsRz4lzm' in 'where clause'*      AND  the line is 'myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();' where the long hash is the account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following WHERE clause:

```
WHERE accName =" + hashedAcc;
```

will cause an error if `accName` is not of type `int`, it needs quotes around it.

You should use parameterized query just like you did in PDO, it avoid errors like this and SQL injections as well.

```
var query = "SELECT userPass FROM 49Users WHERE accName = @hashedAcc";
var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hashedAcc", hashedAcc);
```

Comment: That did it.  So basically need to give it a literal, if I read that right.  I'll have to take a look at the Parameters docs.  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I'm sure it's because the first thing to do is get it working...then worry about best practices.  I knew coming in I should be running parameters and would get yelled at (hyperbole), but I still couldn't get it working either way.

Comment: @user2079828 like grant pointed out adding quotes is not 100% safe, you should manage to use parameter its not hard at all

Comment: Personally, I'd go a step further and avoid SQL queries completely by using an ORM :)